# SonarQube community edition for commercial project

Tags: sonarqube

I am analyzing SonarQube to use it for our closed source product which is mostly .Net and web technologies. 
Are there any caveats to using community edition for commercial projects? 
What is the limit on the lines of code that community edition can scan?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

SonarQube Community Edition is free of charge without any LOC (Lines Of Code) limitations. You can use if freely in your commercial project.

Comment: I will give it a spin, will update this thread if I find any surprises.

Comment: @DevOpsy Did you find any limits or issues? I'm looking at using it for the same use case currently.

Comment: @Erdss4: community edition is pretty good, didn't hit any limits on the LOC. We bought developer edition and it has additional features mainly OWASP top 10 security scanning and branch analysis. Still analyzing and learning.

Comment: Could you provide the source or a reference to this answer please?

Comment: You can check Plans & Pricing: https://www.sonarsource.com/plans-and-pricing/ or read this explanation about LOC usage: https://community.sonarsource.com/t/loc-limit-explanations/5082